# What is the linux-image-extra package for and do I need it?

Tags: kernel

I occasionally update my kernel from this web site 
http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/

I have been always downloading 3 deb files for installing 
linux header all, linux image and linux headers. I noticed one more deb file recently for 64 bit kernel called Linux-image-extra.

I would like to know what does kernel file **Linux-image-extra** do and should I also install it?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

## This answer is obsolete for modern Ubuntu releases

Without the `extra` package, most hardware won't work!

#### It contains extra drivers left out of the base kernel package; install it only if you need these drivers

Sometimes, a specific variant of the *linux-image* is slimmed down by removing the less common kernel modules (drivers).  In this case, the *linux-image-extra* package simply contains all of the "extra"  kernel modules which were left out.

- Officially, [this only happens for the `-virtual` image](http://ubuntu.5.n6.nabble.com/PATCH-0-2-linux-image-extra-support-td365008.html); the most common hypervisors (Virtualbox, VMWare, Xen, KVM) emulate a well-defined and restricted set of hardware, so removing unnecessary drivers which increase the size of the kernel/initrd is a good idea. You can always get them back by installing the extras package.
- The kernel team also appears to have adopted this method for some of the mainline-PPA `-generic` kernels; the reasoning and solution remain the same -- if it looks like the base kernel image is missing a module you need, install extras.
- As far as I know, the above approach has not been taken for the Quantal kernels -- only *-virtual* is affected as usual.

Comment: Note that I recommend simply using the latest Quantal kernel instead of the latest "mainline" kernel--on Precise--simply because the former is usually slightly more hardware-compatible.

Comment: That's what I always do :)

Comment: Btw, this is how you can see if the ..-extra is installed: dpkg --get-selections | grep linux-image

Comment: I wonder why is this obsolete?

Comment: @Sajuuk see answer below. It's obsolete because `linux-image-extras` is now more important than it used to be, and should not be removed from desktop systems.

Answer (score 18):

In previous Ubuntu versions, the `linux-image-extras` was optional, tailored for virtual machines / servers.

As of Ubuntu 14.04, `linux-image` is a slim package (for virtual machines), and `linux-image-extras` now contains many drivers required for desktops.

In particular, `usb-hid` (keyboard support), is only present once you install the `linux-image-extras` package. A common mishap, which results in `TTY1` hanging on boot, and unable to login using a keyboard.

Mainline kernels are shipped using a single `linux-image` package, such as `linux-image-3.19.0-031900rc1-generic_3.19.0-031900rc1.201412210135_amd64.deb`

Comment: It also includes a bunch of network drivers your card might use. Bottom line: DO NOT uninstall this package.

Comment: Without linux-image-extras, my usb mouse worked fine, but my usb keyboard didn't. I'm sure this change from a `-virtual` package wastes a lot of people's time.