# How do I get amilo-rfkill support on a non-pae laptop? (a.k.a. where to get 3.5 kernels for oneiric)

Tags: 11.10, kernel, rfkill

The [driver](http://lxr.linux.no/#linux+v3.3/drivers/platform/x86/amilo-rfkill.c) seems to be in the 3.3 tree, but I just installed 3.3.7 from the mainline kernel repository, cause I [thought it would have the driver](http://lkml.indiana.edu/hypermail/linux/kernel/1203.1/01988.html) (3.3-rc7). But it is not included.

There are no newer kernels for oneiric, and I can't use precise or quantal kernels cause they require PAE and I don't have that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I compiled my own amilo-rfkill.ko using [this guide](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/build-linux-kernel-module-against-installed-kernel-source-tree.html), the amilo-rfkill.c sources from the Git snapshot of 3.3.7 and the kernel headers from the Ubuntu mainline kernel repository.

Answer (score 2):

A couple of things:

- Non-PAE (aka *generic i386*) kernels are available until Precise, but *not for* Quantal
- Just because a driver is in the kernel (source) tree **does not mean** it is included in a specific build of the kernel (that depends on the kernel configuration for that build)
- *amilo-rfkill* **is available** in the ***PAE*** i386 kernel 3.4/3.5 mainline builds for *Quantal*, as part of the [**`linux-image-extra`**](https://askubuntu.com/questions/153023/what-is-the-linux-image-extra-package-for-and-do-i-need-it/153033#153033) package.

  - But it is not available in the Ubuntu kernel team's previous non-PAE builds of the 3.3/3.4 kernels.
  - Unfortunately, if you have no PAE support it looks like you must build the kernel (or at least that module) yourself...

Comment: I get an error though, when installing those highlighted packages: http://pastie.org/4318671

Comment: You may want to file a bug then, because I don't see why they have separate `generic-pae` and `generic` i386 packages if the latter still require PAE support. But otherwise, sorry, it looks like you'll have to build your own kernel to get `amilo-rfkill` support...

Comment: but i don't see any distinct generic{-pae,} packages. i think it's on purpose: https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/ubuntu-devel/2011-November/034399.html

Comment: Sorry, I see that now -- they continued to do that until 3.4-precise, but of course that doesn't have amilo-rfkill...

Comment: how do you see what drivers a specific build contains?

Comment: checking build.log does not seem elegant