# Intel Ethernet not working - *Network UNCLAIMED

Tags: networking, drivers, ethernet

First time Ubuntu user and already having an issue! My ethernet is no longer working (showing *-network UNCLAIMED). Wonder if anybody can help. Outputs are as below.

```
sudo lshw - C net:

    *-network UNCLAIMED
    description: Ethernet controller  
    product: Ethernet Connection (2) I219-V        
    vendor: Intel Corporation       
    physical id: 1f .6             
    bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.6       
    version: 31
    width: 32 bits   
    clock: 33MHz   
    capabilities: pm msi cap_list
    configuration: latency=0   
    resources: memory:ef100000-ef11ffff

lspci -knn | grep Eth -A3; uname -a:

    00:1f.6 Ethernet controller [0200]: Intel Corporation Ethernet Connection (2) I219-V [8086:15b8] (rev 31)
    Subsystem: Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd Ethernet Connection (2) I219-V [1458:e000]
    Kernel modules: e1000e
    05:00.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation DSL6540 Thunderbolt [Alpine Ridge] [8086:1578]
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
    Linux ubuntu 4.10.0-30-generic #34~16.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Wed Aug 2 02:13:56 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

dmesg | grep e100:

    [    0.834386] e1000e: Intel(R) PRO/1000 Network Driver - 3.2.6-k
    [    0.835415] e1000e: Copyright(c) 1999 - 2015 Intel Corporation
    [    0.885478] e1000e: 0000:00:1f.6: Interrupt Throttling Rate (ints/sec) set to dynamic conservative mode
    [    1.799124] e1000e: probe of 0000:00:1f.6 failed with error -2

sudo modprobe e1000e:

no output
```

To be honest, I'm not sure what else I could pull that would help. The device is also stand-alone which i'm sure doesn't help.

Thanks!

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Eth -A3; uname -a` terminal command. Does "no longer working" means it used to work before?

Comment: @Pilot6 Updated with additional ouput. It was working the first time I unstalled Ubuntu 16.04 on this. Then after I shut it down and restart it after all my updates, it stopped connecting to the internet. After that, I  reinstalled ubuntu hoping it would solve the issue but no good.

Comment: Please edit your question to add the result of the terminal command: dmesg | grep e100

Comment: And also `sudo modprobe e1000e`

Comment: This is a kernel bug. I suggest testing the 4.10 kernel. If you are using Ubuntu 16.04, run `sudo apt install linux-generic-hwe-16.04` and reboot.

Comment: Is it possible to do on a standalone without Internet access? Tried it and it can't find packages.

Answer (score -1):

To just help you onto the next step in trying a newer kernel.

You can download the needed packages from multiple places and in multiple ways. One way you could get them is to download them from packages.ubuntu.com You will need this 3 packages for kernel 4.10.0-30-generic:

- [linux-image](https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/amd64/linux-image-4.10.0-30-generic/download)
- [linux-headers-amd64](https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/amd64/linux-headers-4.10.0-30-generic/download)
- [linux-headers-all](https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/all/linux-headers-4.10.0-30/download)
- [linux-image-extra](https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/amd64/linux-image-4.10.0-30-generic/download)

Comment: You forgot `linux-image-extra`.

Comment: I left it out on purpose, however it will not hurt, but could be marked as optional with a reference to https://askubuntu.com/questions/153023/what-is-the-linux-image-extra-package-for-and-do-i-need-it

Comment: Network drivers are there. It is useless without the extra. The accepted answer is obsolete.

Comment: Ok, then we let is stand like that, i have not looked into which exact modules that is excluded from the generic package :)

Comment: Downloaded all 4. Am going to try my best to execute them. thanks all

Comment: Hi All,
Updated the Kernel to 4.10 and rebooted. Nothing changed except `lspci -knn | grep Eth -A3; uname -a` Now shows 4.10.0. Editing outputs in the question.

Comment: Report the bug to launchpad by `ubuntu-bug linux`.

Comment: It claims it's not an official Ubuntu package - also does this mean this is a much more difficult than expected fix?

Comment: What is expected fix? it will report this problem.

Comment: See https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1576953

Comment: If you reboot, it may work.

Comment: Does `dmesg | grep e100` reveal anything new?

Comment: The issue still exists on `5.0.0-23-generic` kernel, the latest driver `3.4.2.4` fails