# network UNCLAIMED (Intel I219-V) Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS

Tags: networking, drivers, 18.04

After Ubuntu updated to 18.04.1 my wired network does not work anymore.

```
ifconfig -a
lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 7015  bytes 562352 (562.3 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 7015  bytes 562352 (562.3 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

wlan1: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.1.57  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.1.255
        inet6 fe80::3e33:ff:fe4e:d687  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 3c:33:00:4e:d6:87  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 29273  bytes 22749547 (22.7 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 24342  bytes 3885122 (3.8 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

Executing lshw:

```
*-network UNCLAIMED
     description: Ethernet controller
     product: Ethernet Connection (2) I219-V
     vendor: Intel Corporation
     physical id: 1f.6
     bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.6
     version: 31
     width: 32 bits
     clock: 33MHz
     capabilities: cap_list
     configuration: latency=0
     resources: memory:df300000-df31ffff
```

I downloaded a driver from intel but could not install it

```
allan@allan-MS-7998:~/Dokumenter/ethernetdriver/e1000e-3.4.0.2/src$ sudo make install
cc1: error: code model kernel does not support PIC mode
/bin/sh: 1: [: -ge: unexpected operator
Makefile:199: *** *** Aborting the build. *** This driver is not supported on kernel versions older than 2.4.0.  Stop.
```

Can anybody help me to activate my wired network again please?

```
sudo modprobe e1000e && dmesg | grep e100
    [sudo] adgangskode for allan: 
    [    1.460981] e1000e: Intel(R) PRO/1000 Network Driver - 3.2.6-k
    [    1.460981] e1000e: Copyright(c) 1999 - 2015 Intel Corporation.
    [    1.517922] e1000e 0000:00:1f.6: Interrupt Throttling Rate (ints/sec) set to dynamic conservative mode
    [    2.448108] e1000e: probe of 0000:00:1f.6 failed with error -2
    [ 2062.302746] e1000e: Intel(R) PRO/1000 Network Driver - 3.2.6-k
    [ 2062.302747] e1000e: Copyright(c) 1999 - 2015 Intel Corporation.
    [ 2062.302939] e1000e 0000:00:1f.6: Interrupt Throttling Rate (ints/sec) set to dynamic conservative mode
    [ 2063.317879] e1000e: probe of 0000:00:1f.6 failed with error -2
    [ 5652.446473] e1000e: Intel(R) PRO/1000 Network Driver - 3.2.6-k
    [ 5652.446474] e1000e: Copyright(c) 1999 - 2015 Intel Corporation.
    [ 5652.446664] e1000e 0000:00:1f.6: Interrupt Throttling Rate (ints/sec) set to dynamic conservative mode
    [ 5653.434212] e1000e: probe of 0000:00:1f.6 failed with error -2
```

Here are some more info:

```
inxi -Fx
System:    Host: allan-MS-7998 Kernel: 4.15.0-32-generic x86_64 bits: 64 gcc: 7.3.0 Console: tty 0
           Distro: Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS
Machine:   Device: desktop Mobo: MSI model: Z170A SLI PLUS (MS-7998) v: 1.0 serial: N/A
           UEFI [Legacy]: American Megatrends v: 1.C0 date: 10/12/2017
CPU:       Quad core Intel Core i7-6700K (-MT-MCP-) arch: Skylake-S rev.3 cache: 8192 KB
```

I was able to install the new driver. But as chili555 said, there must be an underlying problem that should be solved:

```
dmesg | grep e100                                                                                                                                             
[    1.441862] e1000e: Intel(R) PRO/1000 Network Driver - 3.2.6-k
[    1.441862] e1000e: Copyright(c) 1999 - 2015 Intel Corporation.
[    1.510455] e1000e 0000:00:1f.6: Interrupt Throttling Rate (ints/sec) set to dynamic conservative mode
[    2.448105] e1000e: probe of 0000:00:1f.6 failed with error -2
[  379.964316] e1000e: Intel(R) PRO/1000 Network Driver - 3.4.0.2-NAPI
[  379.964316] e1000e: Copyright(c) 1999 - 2017 Intel Corporation.
[  379.964509] e1000e 0000:00:1f.6: Interrupt Throttling Rate (ints/sec) set to dynamic conservative mode
[  380.989857] e1000e: probe of 0000:00:1f.6 failed with error -2
```

What does the last line mean? I have searched the net without finding anything I could use.

Comment: If the driver already present in the kernel, e1000e, is not working as expected, something else is wrong. Installing a different driver will likely not help as the underlying issue is still not fixed. Please edit your question to add the result of the terminal command: `sudo modprobe e1000e && dmesg | grep e100`

Comment: I read this post, https://askubuntu.com/questions/945917/intel-ethernet-not-working-network-unclaimed/945954 but although it looks like the same issue, it's another version of kernel and OS. My Kernel is 4.15.0-32-generic x86_64

Comment: I just updated the BIOS, but it did not change anything. Now BIOS in inxi is:  UEFI [Legacy]: American Megatrends v: 1.E0 date: 06/15/2018

Comment: I booted on a live usb with Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS. It had the same issue. Is it possible that the hardware is broken?

Comment: It is possible but I think there are things we can check first. Is this a dual boot with Windows? Is the result the same if you cold boot to Ubuntu rather than reboot? Does the device work in Windows, if this is a dual boot? Are there settings in the BIOS that deal with interrupts? Is this an integrated card or removable? is it seated properly in the slot?

Comment: Thanks chili555, It is not a dual boot configuration and it is integrated in the motherboard. I did not want to use more time on this issue, I found Ethernet-card to replace the build in card and disabled the old one in BIOS. Normally a live cd/usb would connect without any problems. Having a spare card laying around saves me further agonies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the solution that worked for me.
Ethernet controller I219-V is integrated into the Z170A SLI PLUS motherboard.
Updating the BIOS and booting to an operating system that previously worked - without any luck - convinced me that more work on this issue would be a waste of time.
The solution was to disable I219-V in BIOS and install a new network adapter.
For those who might have a similar problem that they would still try to solve, I apologize. But a new card is so cheap that it does not pay to go on.